# How to increase subreport's textField height as the height of master report's textField?

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport

I would like to resize subreport's text field (before include into main report) like the highest main report's text field.

[image: Screen shot]

As you can see the subreport's text field does not have equal height.

Comment: I have just added an image @AlexK

Answer (score 1):

You need to work with `stretchType`, you can't set the height dynamically in any other way (not considering via java code)

On **reportElement** tag you have the attribute `stretchType`, which you can set to `RelativeToBandHeight` or `RelativeToTallestObject`. I would go for:

```
stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject"
```

However this function will stretch relative to largest object in band, which in your case is the band in the subreport, so probably you should think this the other way around, hence

Set desired field size in subreport then stretch the `textElements` in your main report, to match the height of your subreport.

Comment: I have already try this solutions but this increase only the height on subreport element and not the band of subreport

Comment: @Davide, exactly (I'm trying to state this is post), hence you should stretch the textFields in your mainreport to match the subreports height. You need to invert you report layout.

Comment: Ok, so it's impossible create it more generic... this software have a lot of limitations...

Comment: Its not really limitations, it is more rules of design, I bet there is away to achieve the final result you need, but you need to follow the rule's of design, probably in this case you just need to think backwards from current idea

Comment: You can't change the detail band height of subreport, but you can change the height of your text fields in same band to match the total height of subreport